# Receiving multicast on multiple machines with the same IP address

Tags: c#, networking, multicast

Building a bit of code that does auto configuration of IP addresses, when they start they all have the same IP, this software uses multicast to find the other devices on the network and uses that information to figure it's own IP configuration.

However if they have the same IP they stop receiving multicast packets, but if I force them to have different IPs multicast starts working again. Is multicast tied to IP address or can multiple devices with the same IP receive multicast.

We cannot use APIPA/Link-Local addressing.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multicast does not mean broadcast. Multicast means to send data *only* to devices which have previously requested this multicast group.

You cannot use multicast to reach any previously unconfigured machines. For this you have to, use broadcast (i.e. 255.255.255.255).

Multicast relies on the IGMP protocol, which in turn relies on a working IP unicast setup, which in turn requires that all devices can be uniquely identified by their IP addresses. IGMP messages contain the unicast IP address of the sending device.

In your setup all the nifty optimization algorithms in all the network components along the path (routers, switches, also the devices themselves) will fail since they cannot identify the targets which request the multicast group. They may fail in any random way. It is completely undefined how multiple devices with the same IP address behave.

In your case some network component decides that there is no need to distribute the multicast packets to the involved ports, as there is no unique receiver connected to the port. (I am just speculating here. Any other answer will be correct, too. Just an example to explain how this could behave the way you see it.)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the design of IGMP needing to know the source address and the requirement of having unicast set up beforehand. I solved it by relying on standard broadcast before it's configured and jump to multicast when it's configured.

Comment: That sounds perfect! Limit the use of broadcast as much as possible. It is really just there for such cases where you really need to reach all machines, to get the foot in the door.